# How to get Stretch.Uniform scale in Silvlerlight?

Tags: silverlight, image, scale, stretch

Is it possible to get the scale used to stretch an image in Silverlight?

I have a image that i apply stretch.uniform on. When the browser window re-sizes, the image re-sizes as well. If it is possible to get the scale, other components can be transformed by this scale. Does anyone know how to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SizeChangedEventArgs (raised by the SizeChanged event) contains the members NewSize and PreviousSize.  A little division and you're good to go.